# Why won't this OpenGL program open a window?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am currently trying to learn both C++ and OpenGL, and I am beginning with the following code example:

### simple.cpp

```
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void init() {
        // code to be inserted here
}

void mydisplay() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // need to fill in this part
        // and add in shaders
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        glutCreateWindow("simple");
        init();
        glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
        glutMainLoop();
}
```

It says [here](http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/%7Ee20068/teaching/i3dg&a/2016/compiling.html) that this code can be compiled on MacOS using the following command:

```
gcc -Wno-deprecated-declarations -o hello hello.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Carbon
```

So I adapt the command in the following way:

```
gcc -Wno-deprecated-declarations -o simple simple.cpp -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Carbon
```

This seems to work and creates an executable called `simple`.

I am told that this code should generate a white square on a black background as follows:

[image]

However, when I try to run this file from the terminal using `./simple`, the program runs continuously but nothing happens (that is, no window is generated at all), and so I have to terminate the program from the terminal.

Did I do something wrong here, or is this expected for the given code on MacOS?

---

### EDIT1

To see what would happen, I tried to use the code presented in the [aforementioned guide](http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/%7Ee20068/teaching/i3dg&a/2016/compiling.html):

### hello.c

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void display()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

As the guide says, this is "a simple OpenGL program that does nothing".

I compile it as follows:

```
gcc -Wno-deprecated-declarations -o hello hello.c -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Carbon
```

This compiles fine. However, when I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

```
GLUT Fatal API Usage: main loop entered with no windows created.
zsh: abort      ./hello
```

According to this error message, the program was terminated because no windows were created. However, as I said, my simple.cpp program does *not* terminate (I have to forcefully terminate it), and it *is* written to create windows. So I'm guessing this means that windows *are* created in simple.cpp, but for some reason they just don't show up on MacOS? Can anyone else confirm this? Is the issue perhaps that blank windows don't show up on MacOS, and you need to include other graphical elements in order to make the window show?

---

### EDIT2

The problem is that my understanding is that `glutCreateWindow("simple");` in `simple.cpp` is supposed to create a window with "simple" as its title, so I don't understand why it isn't working.

---

### EDIT3

Thanks to derhass's answer, I was able to make it work:

```
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void init() {
        // code to be inserted here
}

void mydisplay() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // need to fill in this part
        // and add in shaders
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutCreateWindow("simple");
        init();
        glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
        glutMainLoop();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nah, it's not supposed to draw a square. I'm not familiar with GLUT, but it could open a black window at most.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But mine doesn't show anything at all (no window is generated). The program just runs continuously without anything until I terminate it from the terminal.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It seems you were indeed correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu did not include the call to `glutInit()` into your `simple.cpp` example. You can't call any other GLUT commands before this intialization, and doing so results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where in `simple.cpp` should `glutInit(&argc, argv);` go? Should it go before `glutCreateWindow("simple");`?

Comment: ^ YES! Doing this works (see EDIT3)!! Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I thought "you can't call any other GLUT commands before this intialization" would be quite clear.